# Transfer data to other page in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have 3 models dailyTransaction , Contract  , and ContractMonth .

I want transfer some of data from daily Transaction and Contract to the Contract Month page or table  But i do not what is the wrong the table is empty and there no any data .

This is my Contract Month Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
        var contractMonth = _context.ContractMonth.Where(c => c.ContractsId == id).Include(s => s.contracts).Include(d => d.dailyTransactions).ToList();

        return View(contractMonth);
    }
```

This is the view :

```
            <table class="table table-bordered f" cellspacing="0" id="employeetable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ContractsId)</th>

                        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Monthe)</th>
                        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Amount)</th>
                        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Receipt)</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.contracts.Contract_Num)
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.dailyTransactions.Date)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.contracts.AmountOfRent)
                            </td>


                        </tr>
                    }

                </tbody>
            </table>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gv1f8.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKlZ6.png)

Comment: Did you try stepping through your code with breakpoints? Does `contractMonth` contain any values in your controller before you pass it to the view?

Comment: Also, your model is a list, but you use `model.ContractsId` in your view. Doesn't that give a compiler error?

Comment: No I do not do that , the page of Contracts has contracts number , and there are link in all number when i click to that link they go to contract month page and it must show all data about that contract number

Comment: No there are no any error but when i open the contract month page there are no any data

Comment: So set a breakpoint on the line `return View(...) ` and see what the content of the list is. If it's empty there, your data access is the problem, if not, your view is the problem.

Comment: They show me , the count is 0

Comment: I will add pic so you can understand me correctly

Comment: Can you please see the pic i added , so when i click to the contract month the contract month page show but it is empty

Comment: Learn how to [use breakpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-breakpoints?view=vs-2019) and step through your code with the debugger. Inspect the value of the variable `contractMonth` inside your `Index` method after you've clicked 'Contract Month'.

Comment: what is return this? var contractMonth = _context.ContractMonth.Where(c => c.ContractsId == id).Include(s => s.contracts).Include(d => d.dailyTransactions).ToList();

Comment: OK I will learn how i can use the break point , Thank you

Comment: this return the data of the contract number . But the data now show